# mod_rewrite: Redirect all urls ending with "/video/[anyfilename].mp4"

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Sorry for this probably very noob-style question, but I just can't get it to work.

Here's my current .htacces file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteRule ^_res/.*$ - [L] # all URLs beginning with "_res" are not changed.

# put new fancy rule doing what I want here...

RewriteRule . index.php [L] # all other URLs are redirected to index.php

</IfModule>
```

This works fine. It's redirecting all urls except the ones starting with "_res/" to index.php.

What I need now is that all URLs matching "[anypath]/video/[anyfilename].mp4" will be rewritten to "content/[anypath]/video/[anyfilename].mp4" (which is the actual path of this file on the server - I can't use x-sendfile on this shared web space, thus I need to rewrite large file urls to their actual server locations to avoid php's fileread-function).

From my understanding of these RewriteRules, I think I have to place this rule just before the last one.

Unfortunately my regexp-expertise is practically non-existent.

What I thought should work is this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/video/(^/*)\.mp4$ content/$1/video/$2.mp4 [L]
```

The regexp should mean "starts with any amount of any characters, followed by "/video/", followed by any amount of any characters which are not '/' and ends with ".mp4".

When I insert this into my .htaccess right before the last rule, urls ending with "/video/myvid.mp4" are still rewritten to index.php.

You see me clueless. Any suggestions?

Thanks alot in advance!

Comment: `(^/*)` doesn't mean any character other than `/`. For that you mean to do `([^/]*)`

Comment: Thanks, regexpressions are bending my mind a bit too much it seems...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/content/
RewriteRule ^(.*)/video/([^/]+)\.mp4$ content/$1/video/$2.mp4 [L]
```

And you want to add this rule above the one that routes to `index.php`

Comment: Thank you! This works! But I also had to put your RewriteCond directly before the last rule in my .htaccess (the one routing everythingto index.php). Thanks again!